# Return the value of a variable of type X using a function template

Tags: c++, templates, typename

How can I return the value of a variable in a function template which can accept every type?

For example, assume I have following function:

```
template<typename T>
size_t func(T const&) {
    return sizeof(T);
}
```

It can accept any type like `int`, `unsigned int`, `BSTR` and `long` and return size of type.

But I like to get the value of variable of any type like:

```
template<typename T, valueof typename>
X func(T const&) {
    // << return valueof(T) OR return typeid(T).value OR WHATELSE??? >>
}
```

For example, I need above to return `Hello World!` when I use it like `func<BSTR>("Hello World!")`. I need above to return `123456` when I use it like `func<int>(123456)`.

I already know how to get the variable type's name using `typeid(T).name()`, but don't know how to get value of a variable which has a `T` type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I too thought that @Ron's solution bellow is what you need. If it's not, your grossly under-specified your problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller under-specified meant?

Comment: Meant you didn't explain what you want well at all. "I want `X` for `foo(X)`" begs an obvious solution.

Comment: @StoryTeller You're right, given answer is what I need, but I am unable to explain what I want at all correctly in this time. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply return the parameter's value:

```
template <typename T>
T func(const T& param) {
    return param;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  What should I do If I want to convert above returning parameter to a only one type `wstring`? I think it is impossible because universal conversions cannot be done from same function. Am I right?

Comment: @GTAVLover - [`std::to_wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring)?

Comment: Yes **any type** of return parameter to a `wstring`. Because I want this value in future to assign into correct data type in a `VARIANT`.

Comment: @StoryTeller I found answer to my second problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575676/how-to-convert-anything-to-string-implicitly).